# How force Jenkins to show UI always in English?

Tags: language, user-interface, jenkins

I'm using Google Chrome. When I'm using Jenkins (This is remote service, I don't have control over it) then part of UI is displaying in my local language. How can I tell Jenkins to always display messages in English?

Answer (score 51):

Another way to achieve this:

Install the `Locale` plugin.
You can set the default language for all users, no matter the language configured in their browser.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin

Comment: Weird, it would be nice to have this option in settings.

Comment: I agree, but this is how you set the default language for all users.

Answer (score 34):

It can be done in Chrome by setting default language in settings, and it's probably working on other browsers but I didn't test it.
[image]

Comment: To clarify (wasn't obvious to me): drag the desired language to the top of the list.

Comment: I don't want to change my Chrome language but Jenkins is so badly translated in my language.

Answer (score 31):

1. Click **Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > ['Available' tab]**
2. In the Filter, search for: *Locale* .
3. Click on **Locale Plugin** checkbox and **Install without restart** button.
4. After installation is complete:

   - Under **Manage Jenkins > Configure System** there should be a "*Locale*" section.
   - Enter the default *language_LOCALE* code for English: **en_US**
   - Click on **Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users** checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Chrome plugin to change Request Headers on domain base (I'm using "Header Hacker" but I think there are many other plugins of that kind) and replace the "Accept-Language" header for your jenkins domain to "en-US,en;q=0.5".

Comment: Great solution, I didn't know about this possibility. Easy to use also on other domains.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like chrome has an issue on this,
It kept sending Hebrew as the first option in the
`Accept-Language` on the header
although English was set to be the top-language on the list (Chrome settings > Languages)

**Solution**
And only after I've added some other language (Russian for instance) and set it to be the 'top' and then set the English back to be the 'top' it solved!

Answer (score 0):

If doing this in CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise/Core, you'll need to get the plugin from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/locale/ and upload it in ${OpCenterURL}/pluginManager/advanced .

When installed, in **Manage Jenkins > Configure System** in "Locale" section put `en_US`
and check *Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users* as it seems not working without it.